# Where to add content in Server

Tags: php, web, debian, remote-server

I have rented a Debian server using [gandi.net](http://www.gandi.net/). I linked the server to a domain name. When I go on the web on `my_domain_name.com`, I get :

> It works!
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

This proves that `apache2` is running, right? So the question is where do I add content?
In `/home/username/` or where ?

I'm trying to run some `index.php` file and I don't know where to put it in order to run it. What's the path?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is specific to the configuration settings of a particular service provider. You should seek the support resources of that provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default document root for apache2 is `/var/www` but that can be reconfigured if necessary.

To be sure that Apache is indeed running you can type:

```
ps -ef | grep apache
```

If this line of terminal code does not return something Apache is not running. If it returns something it is.

Good luck with your web server.

Comment: Thanks ! Apache is running !

Answer (score 0):

Apache has a default directory in somewhere like `/var/www`, but you can configure it to serve content in other directories. See [Apache DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot)